# how to check if record exists using hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am new to hibernate. I am trying to implement a business rule where i need to check if a record exists in the database to continue different path based on the existance /not.

I am trying to ask if there is a light weight way to see if a record exists in database.

please point me to the documentation if there are some available.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

When you know the primary key value, please take a look at `EntityManager#find` (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find(java.lang.Class,java.lang.Object).

Answer (score 0):

More lightweight solution is use:

```
getReference

<T> T getReference(java.lang.Class<T> entityClass,
                   java.lang.Object primaryKey)
```

> Get an instance, whose state may be lazily fetched. If the requested
>   instance does not exist in the database, the EntityNotFoundException
>   is thrown when the instance state is first accessed. (The persistence
>   provider runtime is permitted to throw the EntityNotFoundException
>   when getReference is called.)

getReference method are not required to be invoked within a transaction context

Comment: this was helpful?, if it was, please dont forget to upvote the answer.